# How to display footer menus in wordpress

Tags: themes

I have an question. I've been registered footer menus from the following function.

```
// Register Navigation Menus
register_nav_menus( array(
    'footer_menu' => 'Footer Menus',
) );
```

but can i know how to show this on footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register the menu, as you have done, and then use the function `wp_nav_menu()` in the template file where you want to display the menu.

```php
wp_nav_menu( array(
   'theme_location' => 'footer_menu',
));
```